# RefineryCMS with existing devise model (not user.rb)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, refinerycms

I am trying to integrate refinerycms with my existing rails app and i want refinery to share an existing devise model that is called "employee" instead of "user".  Can this be done?

This [Guide hints that it is possible](http://refinerycms.com/guides/with-an-existing-rails-31-devise-app) but doesn't explain how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to work though it [using this tutorial](http://www.synaptian.com/blog/posts/integrating-refinery-rails-3-2-into-your-existing-rails-app). I basically replaced "user" with "employee" throughout the entire tutorial and it works.

Comment: Any useful links on dis ? Please help if someone was able to do the same :)